# StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle Translatable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, stofdoctrineextensions

I'm building Symfony 2 app with two languages i have implement the Translatable from StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle. The Translatable make other table ext_translations and store the translations.

**Here is the table which i will use to translate (Objects table):**

[image]

**Here is the table ext_translations (ext_translations table):**

[image]

When i run the code to save the translation for some reason in the ext_translations table.

```
    $entity = $em->getRepository('ObjectsBundle:Object')->find(1);
    $entity->setTitle('my title in ru');
    $entity->setTranslatableLocale('ru'); // change locale
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
```

On creation it write the title in the object table but later on update it is updating only the ext_translations table.

How is handle the update and creation in symfony 2 with two languages?

Do I need to make a copy of those inputs and store them in one time submit. For example in the Object table i have title do I need to have :

```
<input type="text" name="title_bg">
<input type="text" name="title_en">
```

And when they are submitted change the parameter local:

```
 $entity->setTranslatableLocale('ru'); -- or what lang parameter we have
```

And then submit whit the upper code. What is the best solution for this kind of applications?

Comment: What's the locale in your parameters.yml?

Comment: parameters:
    locale: en

and  default_locale:  "%locale%"

Comment: I think you are talking about the config right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "non translation table" texts (the ones in the proper entity) are the ones from your default locale. So usually it is "en" (or more properly is should be en_US or en_GB).

if you want to have your translation to be russian by default ("ru" or better "ru_RU"), you should set your default locale as that.

The translations (and entries to your ext_translations table) are the entries for the non-default-locale translations.

To set your default locale, go to the parameters.yml.dist and set

```
parameters:
    [...]
    locale: de
```

Run `php composer.phar install` to transfer it into your parameters.yml. You can of course edit it directly in the parameters.yml but then it might be overwritten again after a composer update/install

edit (for the comment):
If you have problems with CRUD (or most likely the U), you always have to make sure that you have the proper entity loaded. The translatable extension always relies on the locale you set inside the entity.
To load the proper entity with the text you want to edit, you have to do the following on load

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('ObjectsBundle:Object')->find(1);
$entity->setTranslatableLocale('ru'); // change locale
$em->refresh($entity);
```

This you would do if you wanted to edit your non-default-language-texts.
While saving you still have to make sure to properly set the locale in your entity as well (as mentioned by you above).

edit #2: 
https://gist.github.com/Koalabaerchen/8ed60894cdbbdcd42f3c
This is an example of a _locale parameter set inside the session of a user (if not existant). Tested with Symfony 2.7.7 and below

If you want to switch the _locale of the user session (to get other translations) you simply have to create a controller action that sets the _locale session attribute so the other language gets loaded "magically" by the translatable bundle.

Comment: Ok i understand about the default but how to handle the CRUD is it only to change this local? And how will be the best practice (set sessions or two input fields)?

Comment: two input fields you have to make sure you create hem from the same entity, but one of the fields (the translation, not the default) won't be mapped inside your FormType.

Sessions I'll put up my locale listener in another edit

Comment: I'm not getting you here can you explain with example.

Comment: If you want to do it in one form, you have to add both fields to your form in Symfony (of course). But only one of those fields is in your entity, that is put into the form. The other field (the translation field) then needs to be set `mapped = false` and handled on saving of the form. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#mapped

Comment: i wonder why you have in the listener

`code 

if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }`

and in the first if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale'))  why you not set there also the locale?

Comment: It checks if there's a _locale=de (or similar) in your url and sets it to that language. That is basically so I can redirect users that don't have a session yet to my page hin the language of his desire since there is no language parameter in the routes